# know how to use a language model in tensorflow Lite?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, nlp, tensorflow-lite

Does anyone know how to use a language model in TensorFlow Lite? I have a generated language model with an `LSTM` structure in TensorFlow. I have already converted it to `.tflite` for use on android. Now my question is how can I use it? My intention is to use that model to predict the next word in a sentence. The original model works perfectly in Python, now what I need is for it to work and make predictions in Java or Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways:

1. Add the `.tflite` model in assets folders, implement it to build Gradle file and then finally import that model to carry out requirements in java/kotlin. as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhjBDxpAOIc)
2. By using firebase, firebase provides custom machine learning model deployment options.
   you can add the model to firebase and use it as a remote [service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5-BDRCAkMI). the link to [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/use-custom-models).

I'd recommend the first method if your model size is small & if you want to run your app offline.